# Page elements shaking due to CSS effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added a ripple effect to happen when the user clicks anywhere on a div. It works well except that when the page is full screen, the element shake and go blurry for until the ripple disappears.

**Here's the JS for the effect:**

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
  // Remove any old ripples
  $(".ripple").remove();

  // Setup
  var posX = $(this).offset().left,
      posY = $(this).offset().top,
      buttonWidth = $(this).width(),
      buttonHeight = $(this).height();

  // Add the element
  $(this).prepend("<span class='ripple'></span>");

 // Make it round
  if(buttonWidth >= buttonHeight) {
    buttonHeight = buttonWidth;
  } else {
    buttonWidth = buttonHeight; 
  }

  // Get the center of the element
  var x = e.pageX - posX - buttonWidth / 2;
  var y = e.pageY - posY - buttonHeight / 2;


  // Add the ripples CSS and start the animation
  $(".ripple").css({
    width: buttonWidth,
    height: buttonHeight,
    top: y + 'px',
    left: x + 'px'
  }).addClass("rippleEffect");
});
```

**And the CSS:**

```
.ripple {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(249, 107, 107, 0.8);
  transform: scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100; 
}
.rippleEffect {
    animation: rippleDrop .4s linear;
}

@keyframes rippleDrop {
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/f1apoya1/5/) the fiddle but you can't see the issue as it's a minimized preview, so [here's](http://test9489482.bitballoon.com/) another link where you can see it.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Working fine for me: Chrome 53, 1080p screen. Even tried F11.

Comment: @yuriy636 That's strange... perhaps it's just my computer or screen size (1366 x 768).

Comment: Tested with ubuntu ff and chrome: everything works right.
Try this ripple implementation:
http://codepen.io/440design/pen/iEztk
Do you still have shaking with it?

Comment: I see what you are talking about. I don't think it is just you, maybe hard to notice or maybe doesn't happen on all versions of browsers

Answer (score 1):

Change your code 
FIRST:

```
<div style="visibility: visible; position: fixed;" id="choose" class="centered">
            <div style="position: fixed; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 100%; left: 50%; top: 50%;" id="choose-cont">
            <h3>You are X, the computer is O.</h3>
            <button id="okay">OK</button>
            <button id="surprise">No</button>
            </div>
   </div>
```

2.

```
<div style="position: fixed; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width:   100%; left: 50%; top: 50%;" id="choose-cont">
            <h3>You are X, the computer is O.</h3>
            <button id="okay">OK</button>
            <button id="surprise">No</button>
            </div>
```

You can also add that in your CSS i just paste to you that you can see cahanges!

NOTE - You need chack you YQ code, i can overwrite circle 
picture:http://prntscr.com/clwp72

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this class:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Cancel it and you will not have flickering. 
I'm guessing that the problem is with the transform attribute. You insert and remove items into the DOM and it has to recalculate the position.

When I clear all styles from the class- flickering is gone:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh81ebq5/1/)